# How to calculate the six least significant numbers of a big integer

Tags: javascript, numbers, biginteger, complex-numbers

I am writing some code to get the six least significant digits of a number.

Example: For N = 14930352, the least significant digits would be 930352 and for
N = 102334155, answer is 334155

Which one can do by N%1000000.

For 354224848179262000000 the answer is 915075, which I am getting wrong answer by using above method, I am getting 997056.

Comment: You need to use [BigInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt). But, the number cannot be stored as number type in the variable. It needs to be saved as a BigInt type. `354224848179262915075n % 1000000n` returns `915075n`

Comment: javascript != c# please correct your tags

Comment: Why would the answer not be 179262?

Comment: *...For 354224848179262000000 the answer is 915075...* I don't see any way to get 915075 from that.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk best guess: 354224848179262000000 is the result of some other computation that got rounded to Number precision (losing the ...915075 tail it would have had at full precision) when it should have been stored as a BigInt instead. I think this question should be clarified or closed; it's not even clear whether it's about JS or C#.

Comment: And another problem with tags: it's nothing about complex numbers (numbers in the form of x + y∙i where i² = -1)

Answer (score -1):

One way you could do is by converting this number to string, slicing the last 6 digits and convert back to number.

Comment: That approach wouldn't address "For 354224848179262000000 the answer is 915075" though (which needs to be clarified in the question because right now it doesn't make any sense).

Answer (score -2):

`

```js
let leastSignificantDigits = value => {

    const valueArr = [...`${value}`];

    return valueArr.slice(valueArr.length-6).join('');    
    
}


leastSignificantDigits(14930352)
'930352'
leastSignificantDigits(102334155)
'334155'
```

Comment: This is not a great answer because it (1) doesn't contain any explanation, (2) doesn't solve the OP's problem (`354224848179262000000` returning an unexpected result), and (3) is effectively the same as `value => value.toString().substr(-6)`, but much less efficient due to the needless conversion to array and back.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).